# How to tell GCC that input file is assembler even if it's really .c?

Tags: gcc, assembly, c-preprocessor, pragma

I have an unusual situation: I have an assembler file, which has .c extension and I cannot change build scripts, where this file is defined as "C" type. However, I can build it with the same GCC options if I rename it into .asm or *.s.

Is there any standard method to make GCC to think an input file is Assembler even if it has **.c** extension?

I can't change build script! I can only change the .c file. So, maybe there is a way to set command-line option '-x assembler' using preprocessor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds a bit complicated, but if you use bash or anything similar you can alias gcc to a script you'll write and in this script when it gets the file you want to change behavior use the `-x assembler` parameter with gcc and act normally in otherfiles.

Comment: Thanks, -xassembler works, but -x assembler not. maybe GCC bug